# How to wrap around from 10 to 1 in MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, sql-limit

I have a total number of 10 employees and I have to display the next 3 employees details on my page and I tried the below code.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM employee
 where empid > 1 
   and is_active = 1 
 order 
    by empid ASC 
 limit 0 , 3
```

and I am getting the output 2,3,4 which is correct.

Now my issue is, If the empid is 10 then I am getting the empty row. Is it possible to display the `1,2,3` when the empid is `10` or if the empid is `8` the display `9,10,1`

I mean I want it to wrap around from `10 to 1`.

```
empid | Name      | Position   | Office   | Age
  1   | Airi      | Accountant | Tokyo    | 33
  2   | Angelica  | Officer    | London   | 47
  3   | Ashton    | Technical  | Francisco| 66
  4   | Bradley   | Software   | London   | 41
  5   | Brenden   | Engineer   | Francisco| 28
  6   | qodjf     | Accountant | Tokyo    | 33
  7   | Angelica  | Officer    | New York | 50
  8   | Ashton    | Technical  | Francisco| 30
  9   | zxysz     | Software   | London   | 50
  10  | Brenden   | Engineer   | Francisco| 28
```

I tried to create a table in [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) but I am getting the error. I am using PHPMyAdmin. So i added table here.

Comment: What if empid is 9?

Comment: @forpas, then the output will be 10,1,2

Comment: @nbk, Why, Any reason?

Comment: @nbk, Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the condition `empid > ? DESC` in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee 
WHERE is_active = 1
ORDER BY empid > ? DESC, empid LIMIT 3
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b387720b443cc15423353c91b25730a9).

Comment: Let me try this. Give me sometime

Comment: It's it's working perfectly, Thanks to you for the help.Upvote from my side